# Replacing string with back reference preceeded with backslash

Tags: regex, string, elixir

I want to replace all `_` and `%` in a string with `\_` and `\%` respectively.

I tried

```
String.replace("_foo%_bar", ~r/_|%/, "\\\\0")
```

But this just produces `"\\0foo\\0\\0bar"`.

How to properly escape the first backslash not to affect the back reference syntax?

Comment: You can use a character list: `[92, 48]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
String.replace("_foo%_bar", ~r/_|%/, "\\\\\\0")
```

Here, `"\\\\"` defines 2 literal `\` chars that are parsed as a single literal `\` char in the replacement, and `"\\0"` is parsed as a `\0`, the backreference to the whole match value.

You may also use

```
String.replace("_foo%_bar", ~r/_|%/, ~S(\\\0))
```

to avoid overescaping, as [`~S` sigil](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#interpolation-and-escaping-in-sigils) does not allow escape sequences and backslashes have literal meanings inside them.

Answer (score 2):

You need one more pair of backslashes:

```
iex(1)> IO.puts String.replace("_foo%_bar", ~r/_|%/, "\\\\\\0")
\_foo\%\_bar
```

But I'd suggest using `Regex.replace/3` with a function as a callback here:

```
iex(2)> IO.puts Regex.replace(~r/_|%/, "_foo%_bar", &("\\" <> &1))
\_foo\%\_bar
```